# Comparison of AUCs if dichotomous variable differs

Tags: r, proc-r-package

Can the function roc.test only be used to compare ROC-curves in cases were the dependent (dichotomous) variable is the same for both ROC-Curves (roc1 and roc2) or can it also be used if there are two different dependent variables?

```
RocI <- roc(dat$I, dat$SIDI.F, ci = TRUE)
RocO <- roc(dat$O, dat$SIDI.F, ci = TRUE)


roc.test(RocI, RocO, method=c("bootstrap"), alternative = c("greater"),
         paired=NULL, reuse.auc=T, boot.n=2000, boot.stratified=TRUE,
         parallel=FALSE, conf.level=0.95)
```

This is how the data looks like:

```
   ID I A SIDI.F
1   1 0 0     50
2   2 1 1     13
3   3 1 1     13
4   4 0 0     12
5   5 0 0     13
6   6 0 0     15
7   7 0 0     23
8   8 0 0     34
```

Comment: Well, what is the result of this code, does it give you an error?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, it works without error. I tried to understand what R does and read Robin et al. 2011 and the paper the code is based on (Hanley & McNeil; 1983). However, the situation, in which the same sample is divided in two different ways (in my case, either through "I" or though "O" = to different dichotomous variables while the continuous variable stays the same) is not mentioned in Hanley & McNeil. Thus, I am unsure if the calculation is suitable for this case.

Comment: To make is less abstract: Finding out how to compare ROC curves with different dichotomous variables within the same sample is very valuable for questions like: Does the SIDI-F score better predict anxiety (roc1) or depression disorders (roc2)?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`roc.test` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.18.0/topics/roc.test):

> This function compares two correlated (or paired) or uncorrelated (unpaired) ROC curves.

So yes, you can use this function if your ROC curves are built from different variables.

Make sure to set `paired=FALSE` explicitly, just to be sure to use the unpaired tests (although this would likely be detected correctly if you set it to `NULL` as you did).

Comment: Thanks! I just think that my data is somehow correlated (see edited data frame below). The same person is categorized with "I" (anxiety yes or no) and "O" (depression yes or no) and also answers the questionnaire "SIDI-F". However, my data is not paired as it is usually described (same person answering one questionnaire twice while the dichotomous variable stays the same). But my data is also not unpaired as it is usually described (two independent samples answering the same questionnaire and being categorized using the same dichotomous variable.)I am confused whether one category fits at all.